# Dynamically pull from a database depending on dropdown result

Tags: sql, database, forms, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am currently pulling the information I need from my database but would like the information being displayed to change dependant on the dropdown result. I have done some research and think the best way to do this will be using a form but am not sure how it will work.

Here is the code I have below:

```
      <section id="compare">

    <select>
      <option>Select Gym</option>       
      <option>fitness first</option>
      <option>anytime fitness</option>
      <option>the gym</option>
      <option>its leisure ltd</option>
      <option>the armoury</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option>Select Gym</option>       
      <option>fitness first</option>
      <option>anytime fitness</option>
      <option>the gym</option>
      <option>its leisure ltd</option>
      <option>the armoury</option>      
    </select>

    <section id="left"> 
    <?php

    mysql_select_db("gyms", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gym WHERE id='1'") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          echo "<h1>" . $row['name'] . "</h1>";
          echo "<p><h6>type</h6>" . $row['type'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p><h6>price</h6>" . $row['price'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p><h6>hours</h6>" . $row['hours'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p><h6>parking</h6>" . $row['parking'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p><h6>facilities</h6>" . $row['facilities'] . "</p>";
          } 
    ?>      
    </section>

    <section id="right">
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gym WHERE id='2'") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
          echo "<h1>" . $row['name'] . "</h1>";
          echo "<p><h6>type</h6>" . $row['type'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p><h6>price</h6>" . $row['price'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p><h6>hours</h6>" . $row['hours'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p><h6>parking</h6>" . $row['parking'] . "</p>";
          echo "<p><h6>facilities</h6>" . $row['facilities'] . "</p>";
          } 

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
    </section>

  </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right, you need to use a form implementing the POST method which posts the selected value in the form, matching the 'id' field included in your database.

Here is an example:

```
<form action="compare.php" method="post">
    <select name="gyms-1">
      <option value="0">Select Gym</option>         
      <option value="1">fitness first</option>
        </select>
    <select name="gyms-2">
      <option value="0">Select Gym</option>         
      <option value="1">fitness first</option>      
    </select>
    <input name="send" id="send" type="submit" value="compare" />
</form>
```

Then here is the PHP code which implements the post method:

```
<?php
    $gyms=$_POST['gyms-1'];
    $jimmy=$_POST['gyms-2'];

    mysql_select_db("gyms", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gym WHERE id='$gyms'") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          echo "<h1>" . $row['COLUMN NAME'] . "</h1>";
          echo "<p><h6>type</h6>" . $row['COLUMN NAME'] . "</p>";
          } 

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gym WHERE id='$jimmy'") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
          echo "<h1>" . $row['COLUMN NAME'] . "</h1>";
          echo "<p><h6>type</h6>" . $row['COLUMN NAME'] . "</p>";
          } 

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This should allow you to display multiple rows in your database depending on the value selected by the user. Any problems give me a shout!

Answer (score 0):

User jquery .change. For example along the way of:

```
   $("#left").change(function(){ 
    $("#right").html("[post your data]");
   });
```